# PIL module in python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-imaging-library

I have no problem running the program with vscode, but when I try to run the program using the terminal, I get the *ImportError*. And when I want to **install the pillow** module with the pip install pillow command, the terminal writes that this module> l has already been installed. Does anyone know where the problem is?

Example code:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('known_d2.png')
print(img)
```

*1. response From terminal*

**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "pillow_MOUDLE.py", line 1, in 
from PIL import Image
`ImportError`: No module named PIL**

*2. response From vscode*
**<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGB size=1290x1000 at 0x7F873E855A60>**

Comment: Install with `python -m pip install pillow`. This ensures that you're installing to the correct interpreter's path.

Comment: @MichaelRuth I see where you're coming from, but not if OP uses `python3` ...

Comment: @MarkSetchell, yup. In that case OP would need to have aliased `python3` as `python` or know the path to the proper interpreter. Hopefully, OP's VSCode terminal is set up so that the proper interpreter is aliased as `python`.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the import mechanism of python, it can run in the IDE compiler because the compiler has created the project and can identify the modules to be introduced;
However, it cannot be recognized on the CMD command line. So there are several solutions

1. Add the environment variable pythonpath and add your project address in the variable
2. Create in the python installation directory .pth file. The content in the file is your project address.
3. For the solution to your current problem, "pip install pillow" in shell can solve it.

Of course, the above is based on the premise that the shell and vsocde use the same interpreter.